# How to capture the filename of the browse button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I am new to ROR. I want to capture the filename of the browse button after selected the file with the extension. And i want to store the filename into the File_name column in the database. Please help me to do that. Is it possible to get the full path of the file stored in the File_name column instead of just a filename? please suggest me to do that. I dont want to upload the file. Just i want a filename to store.

```
View(New)
--------------
<div class="pro-data-imports">
  <%= form_for @pro_data_import do %>

  <div class="field">
    Browse the file to upload:<br />
    <%= file_field_tag :File_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Import File' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>


Controller
----------

class Pro::DataImportsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout "layouts/enr/energy_master"

  def index
    @pro_data_imports = Pro::DataImport.all
  end

  def new
    @pro_data_import = Pro::DataImport.new
    @pro_data_import.updated_by = current_user
  end

  def create
    @pro_data_import = Pro::DataImport.new(params[:pro_data_import])
    @pro_data_import.updated_by = current_user

  end 
end

Model
-------
I have File_name, File_validate, :updated_by Columns
```

Comment: I don't think the browser will ever give you the full filename path. It shouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, Thats the feedback I got it from all. Thank you for the answer. Could you help me to get just the file name of the browser button and save it to the database.

Comment: I guess you could do it with client side scripting and css. Hide the submit button with css and get the value from the input field with javascript. I don't think it is possible with only Rails.

Comment: I am very new to rails. I am bit confused to do that. Ok Imagine that instead of browse button there is the textbox button. I want to store the textbox data into the database. Just the textbox data.

Comment: you should try to use the text_field_tag instead of file_field_tag.

Comment: How to call the storedprocedure for my create button? instead of create the field. I want to execute the stored procedure.? Give any example in the answer fields... please

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want to call a stored procedure I don't know if a rails model is the best way to go.

Comment: yeah.... that's what i am asking. How to call the stored procedure through model. Please provide an example. When i click the create button in the View, it calls this stored procedure in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you meant by that. In your comments you mentioned to want to know, how to call the store procedure with two parameters. If its your database is SQL try the following and change your field name as per your spec.

In your model, create a method

```
def update
  parameters = [self.File_Name, File_Location]
  parameters.map!{|p| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote p}
  sql = "your store procedure name"(#{parameters.join(',')})"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

In your controller,

Inside your create method, call the update method.

```
def create
  @update = Pro::DataImport.new(params[:pro_data_import])
  @pro_data_import.updated_by = current_user
  @update.update
  .........
  ...
end
```

I hope it will help. This is just an example to follow. Do not copy and paste.. :)

Comment: I don't know what you done in the second line of the controller. :P

Comment: Oh, Thank you Sri. It does very useful to me.